# Stuck with Enqueue Styles for multiple css files in a child theme

Tags: wp-enqueue-style

I am brand new to WP and I have been reading a ton of posts and trying out different examples out to get the wp_enueue_style to work for me but to no avail.

I am using refur wp theme and I made the child according to the wp documentation.  I then copied the style.css file from the parent theme and put it into my child directory and used the wp_enqueue_style function given on the wp documentation show below.  I changed the color of the text in the child directory and it shows up perfect in my website.  Now I am trying to add different css files for different pages.

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() .  '/style.css' );

}
?>
```

So this is where I get lost in trying to implement different .css files.  I made a new css file named form.css and stuck it in the child theme directory.  I then put this code in to get it to use form.css instead of style.css if the page is something

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {

if ( is_page( 'home' ) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri(), '/style.css' );
    }
elseif ( is_page( 'form') {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'form-style', get_template_directory_uri() .  '/form.css' );
    }
}
?>
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong, I am a little confused about the 'form-style' and 'parent-style' handles and how they play a role exactly with the file naming.  Since I have messed around with 'parent-style' name and broken the site.

My understanding so far is with the child theme, the parent theme css is overridden by the css in the child theme directory if anything is different.  The enqueue is a way to load the css into the website instead of using import.  But why do they name it parent-style if its a child css directory?  Also if my parent theme has a couple .css files named font and one other that control only a couple things do I need to put that dependency (shown on the wp documentation child theme example) in the enqueue if I am not overriding it in the child anywhere?

Thank You I have been looking at so many examples and I just cant figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: for [Child_Themes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri`

Comment: Yes you load always the `parent-style` and after that the `child style sheet` which holds 'only' your changes/add-ons. Your `child style.css` can be used as add-on on te `parent style.css` or to make changes which you do not like from the `parent stle sheet`. You could see the `child style sheet` as a supplement on the `parent style sheet` (*which holds extra or corrections on what already exists*). See my answer for the `function`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code in your `functions.php` should load first the `parent` and than the `child` CSS file. What it actually does: Loading the `parent` style sheet and then it will load your `child` style sheet and at last it will load your `form.css`.
 You **must** keep `style.css` in your `child theme` else Wordpress will not recognize it as it!

As already mentioned by yourself the `child style.css` will/should overwrite the `parent style.css` when made changes in the style-sheet.
By creating a `child-theme` we keep the `parent-theme` as it is and when it needs to be upgraded (*only the `parent theme` will be upgraded in that case*) all your changes made in the **`child-theme`** will still exist.

Keep in mind that such is also for other `theme` files. (*e.g. changes which you want to make in the `single.php` you should make in a `child-theme file`,by copying the original `single.php` from the `parent theme` into your `child theme`folder. And there you make those changes.*)

Take a look [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) for detailed explanations.

> Note: Please make always a backup before you edit/add some in a file.

**Updated after comment from OP** 
(*because I am blind and not reading complete question*)

```
function wpse220011_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'parent-style';

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array( $parent_style ) );
    // Load extra styling for Form pages
    if( is_page( 'form' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'form-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 'style-form.css', array() );
    }
    // Load extra styling for single posts
    if( is_single() ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'single-post-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 'style-single.css', array() );
    }

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse220011_theme_enqueue_styles' );
```

> Above is just an example!

- Realize that the extra `style sheets` as used in the code are loading
  on top of the existing `style.css` so it is **extra** code.
- Or you have to copy from the `style.css` file, code which you want to
  change/hide and make in that (*lets say as used in example*)
  `style-form.css` your changes.
- You can use `display: none;` which will display as if the element is
  not there at all, or `visibility: hidden;` however, the element will
  still take up the same space as before.

I did not add `if( is_page( 'home')` because your example shows that it is using the (basic) `styles.css` already so why loading it again?!

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the answer!  I wanted to use different css files for different pages.  So for my home page I wanted a certain stylesheet and for my form page something different.  Which is the reason for child theme style.css for my main page and child theme form.css for my form page.  May I ask for the array( $parent_style) this is because we are dependent on the parent style.css?  Also for the form style why false false for the last two and array() nothing dependent?  I figured I could just use that If elseif code for the different pages to load different css files for each page.

Comment: Sorry for not reading, I have updated the answer. I removed  `false, false` is in this case not needed. To enlighten some more, yes the child theme `style.css` is depending on the parent `style.css`. (*It will not load until the parent `style.css` is loaded.*) 
There are two ways to load the parent `style.css` 1) to include the parent `style.css` in your child theme style.css using `@import`
2) doing it like above by using a `function`. And yes of course, if you want to have another style for `home` just adjust the code to your needs. Please read the link to understand more.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense now.  So I added in just the if (is_page) you showed in your example but it still seems to be loading the child theme changes only and not the text change I made in the style-single.css file.  So I understand now that Parent css file loads > Child style css loads any changes in the new css file > if 'form' then this loads any changes on top of those two above?  I feel like it should be working haha seems to make sense.  I checked the slug name and it says form in wp admin, so lost as to why this text color change is not happening in for my form page.  Thanks again!

Comment: Add-on: you should see now in the source code on the front-end that at least  2 `style sheets` are loaded in the `<head></.head>` 1 is `style.css` and the other is (*from the example*) `style-form.css` when you are on the `form page`. Of course there can/will be more when using `plugins` and the `admin bar`.

Comment: I definitely see it loaded thats a good thing lol.  But the style-form.css text color is not overriding my text color that is in the child theme style.css on my form page. I feel like I am missing something conceptually here, does the if statement style-form.css style not override the child style.css? Thanks Again you are awesome.

Comment: Yes, if you do it correctly it will override the `style.css` code. Example: your `post title` uses probably the `<h1>` CSS style `tag`, copy that at the bottom into your `style-form.css` like  `h1 { font-size:250%;}` and see if the `form page` has now a huge `title` font. It should work but thats all CSS, and I can't give here CSS lessons. (*Remember, you must use the same CSS `tags` when you want to override another*) Good luck.

Comment: I completely understand, all I did was make a copy of style.css renamed it style-form.css and changed the body textarea color which works fine for the child style.css but the style-form.css is not overriding with the new textarea color I chose for the form body.  I also tried adding the h1 tag with the font size at the bottom of style-form.css and it did not change anything on the form page.  Which is why I think I am still doing something wrong.  Thank You!

Comment: I just wanted to say thank you Charles with your help and some more youtube videos I have figured out how to enqueue properly lol.  THANKS!

Comment: Great to hear.Please mark the answer as accepted and rate it so others know it is answered and useful.